# Сложение чисел в словаре в python

Tags: python

```
c = {}
a = {'a': 1}
b = {'b': 2}
```

Хочу сложить 2 числа из ключей a и b, чтоб получился результат c = {'c': 3}

Подскажите как реализовать

Comment: А с чем трудности? Доступ по ключу или сложение двух целых?

Comment: сложение двух целых с разными ключами, не понимаю как сделать

Comment: У целых чисел нет никаких ключей.

Comment: А ключ 'c' это фиксированое значение или должно быть вычесленно?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать

```
dt = {'a': 1,'b': 2}
dt['c']=dt['a']+dt['b']
```

Результат

```
{'a': 1,'b': 2,'c':3}
```